# Push-уведомления продолжают приходить после отписки от них

Tags: java, android, push-уведомления

Моё приложение реализовывает `push-уведомления`. Всё работает отлично (сервер шлёт уведомления). При закрытии приложения я произвожу разрегистрацию токена:

```
GCMRegistrar.unregister(this);
```

Токен удален, но уведомления всё равно приходят. Если открыть приложение — мы получаем новый токен, но приложение и дальше отображает уведомления, отправленные на старый токен.

Почему так происходит?

Comment: А Вы уверенны, что GCMRegistrar.unregister(this); точно вызывается? (может быть Вам пуш и не нужен...)

Comment: Как временное решение - запишите в SharedPreferences флаг типа ПоказыватьПушУведомления, и поднимайте его, или сбрасывайте в зависимости от того, надо ли принимать пуши... И, соответственно, перед тем, как показать уведомление, проверяйте значение флага...

Comment: проблема в сервере, после того как вы отписались, серверу на первый же отправленый пуш возвращается респонз в котором есть код, который нужно обработать. кодов около 10 но действий которые может   выполнить сервер всего 3:
1) remove token
2) update token (replace)
3) re-send push notification

Comment: Так и не понятно из прочитаных комментариев, какое будет решение. Опубликуйте кто-нибудь ответ.

Comment: @tizian done (:

Answer (score 1):

В идеале автоматически всё должно отработать. И после `unregister` при попытке отправить пуш на старый токен должен прийти статус [200 + error:NotRegistered](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes). Но, не всегда всё гладко и я натыкался на случаю, когда после получения нового токена старый всё ещё оставался рабочий.

Поэтому:

1. После вызова `unregister`, нужно на сервер, который пуши отправляет, послать сообщение, что токен больше не валиден и удалить его из базы.
2. После получения нового токена и отправки его на сервак, удалять/затирать прошлый токен.